# Why does the change in position of the setContentView change the behavior of the the app?

Tags: java, android

When I place "setContentView" above the "NumbersClickListners" line the app works as expected.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NumbersClickListners numbersClickListners = new NumbersClickListners();
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        numbers.setOnClickListener(numbersClickListners);

    }
```

But as soon as the "setContentView" is placed below the three lines starting with "NumbersClickListners" the app crashes. The code looks like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        NumbersClickListners numbersClickListners = new NumbersClickListners();
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        numbers.setOnClickListener(numbersClickListners);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

I'm pretty much unsure of the reason for this behavior. Can anybody help me with that please?

Comment: because setContentView is what inflates the view

Comment: @tyczj correct me if I'm wrong when i recall what u just explained. The compiler starts to read the code from setContentView as it's an inflater, due to which the above lines are being skipped, is that right??

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to say, code never gets skipped

Comment: @tyczj Arright, it's clear this time. Btw I got a down vote to this question. Can anyone explain why, so that I could avoid the mistake the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the life of layout.

First of all, you have to create it by declaring XML file, where you do your design in a user-friendly way and name the elements according to your needs.
Now your layout is just a file, that Android doesn't really care about for performance reasons.

Next thing you wanna do is use your layout. To do that your file needs to be converted to internal structure of objects known as ViewGroup and Views. 
This process is called inflating. That's the point where the system can find the views for you by calling findViewById().

So in the second snippet you ask activity to find you a button, which is not inflated. That leads to throwing exception.

Generally speaking, first thing you want to do in the onCreate is to call setContentView().